# How to Toggle Rectangle or circle in Fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to toggle (means render all rectangles, then remove all).
And here is my code snippet:

```
// CWC is current working canvas.
console.log("Toggling Shapes's" + UIConstants.CWC);
// locate CWC.
var objects = UIConstants.CWC.getObjects();
var ShapesObjects = UIConstants.ShapesArray;
// check if array is empty
if (objects.length < 2) {
    // iterating from 2 because 1st object is image.
    // add Shapes from toggle array and make toggle array as empty.
    if (ShapesObjects.length > 0) {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < ShapesObjects.length; idx++) {
            UIConstants.CWC.add(ShapesObjects[idx]);
        }
    }
} else {
    // remove all Shapes and add to toggle array.
    for (var idx = 1; idx < objects.length; idx++) {
        ShapesObjects.push(objects[idx]);
        // remove all previous handlers.
        try {
            UIConstants.CWC.setActiveObject(objects[idx]);
            UIConstants.CWC.remove(UIConstants.CWC.getActiveObject());
        } catch (E) {
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting this to work for first 4 clicks, after that it doesn't work for 3-4 clicks, then again works.
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

use a while loop instead of for loop.
i.e. change 
`for (var idx = 1; idx < objects.length; idx++) {
        ShapesObjects.push(objects[idx]);
        // remove all previous handlers.
        try {
            UIConstants.CWC.setActiveObject(objects[idx]);
            UIConstants.CWC.remove(UIConstants.CWC.getActiveObject());
        } catch (E) {
        }
    }`

to  become 
`while (objects.length > 1) {
            // iterating from 2nd Index because 1st Index is image.
            UIConstants.ROIArray.push(objects[1]);
            //remove all previous handlers.
            try {
                UIConstants.CWC.setActiveObject(objects[1]);
                UIConstants.CWC.remove(UIConstants.CWC.getActiveObject());
            } catch(E) {
                console.log(E);
                break;
            }
        }`